# Is it impossible to node-cache an observable?

Tags: angular

So basically I try doing something like:

```
  public getSomeStuff(id: number): Observable<Mock> {
    if (!this._cache.has(id.toString())) {
      this._cache.set(
        id.toString(),
        this.http.get<Mock>(`http://884r9.mocklab.io/item/${id}`)
      )
    }

    return this._cache.get(id.toString());
  }
```

then in a component I subscribe to the return value which is supposed to be an observable but nothing happens. No requests go to the server.

Inside the service class I also declare `private _cache: NodeCache = new NodeCache();`.

It just doesn't work for some reason.

EDIT:

Here is what the Mock interface looks like:

```
interface Mock {
  id: number;
  value: string;
}
```

The `id` parameter can take two values : 1 and 2;

Comment: Is need to `subscribe` on your `http.get<Mock>`?

Comment: @ChunbinLi yeah I do it in a component and that method is defined in the service. So yeah, it is subscribed, but it returns nothing.

Comment: No, you cannot meaningfully cache an observable, since its purpose is to track the state of a stream. Most people cache the result of a subscription to an observable (in this case, the response to the HTTP request).

Answer (score -2):

try it

```js
  import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

  public getSomeStuff(id: number): Observable<Mock> {
    if (!this._cache.has(id.toString())) {
      return this.http.get<Mock>(`http://884r9.mocklab.io/item/${id}`).pipe(
        tap(response => {
          this._cache.set(id.toString(), response);
        })
      );
    }

    return this._cache.get(id.toString());
  }
```

Comment: I've just tried it. Now the `!this._cache.has(id.toString())` is always executed to `true`.

Comment: Dose `this._cache.set(id.toString(), response);` not executed?

Comment: It does but it always gets resolved to `true`, I mean `!this._cache.has(id.toString())` meaning that `this._cache.has(id.toString())` is always `false`.

Comment: What's the response value? (``http://884r9.mocklab.io/item/${id}``)

Comment: I've edited the question adding the Mock interface. Please, have a look.

Comment: “Try it” is not a very good explanation of how the code works or how it fixes the problem... see [answer].

Comment: @Albert How do you import the `NodeCache`